# Error when passing null parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, parameter-passing

If the created date time is empty or no value in it i want to return whole table. If it contain date I want to return table data greater that that date. here below I submit a code but it gives data when there is a parameter but it show a error like this Procedure `SelectRotarian_AllByCreatedDatetime` 
Procedure or function `SelectRotarian_AllByCreatedDatetime` expects parameter `@createdDateTime`, which was not supplied.

(1 row(s) affected)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectRotarian_AllByCreatedDatetime]
    @createdDateTime varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if (Coalesce(@createdDateTime,'') = '')
    begin
           select [id]
      ,[surName]
      ,[firstName]
      ,[secondName]
      , [address]
      , [gender]
      ,[picture]
      ,[email]
      ,[phoneNumber]
      ,[DOB]
      ,[vocation]
      ,[bloodGroup_id]
      ,[club_id]
      ,[createdDateTime]
    FROM [rotary_rotarian]
     end 
     else 
     begin

           SELECT[id]
      ,[surName]
      ,[firstName]
      ,[secondName]
      , [address]
      , [gender]
      ,[picture]
      ,[email]
      ,[phoneNumber]
      ,[DOB]
      ,[vocation]
      ,[bloodGroup_id]
      ,[club_id]
      ,[createdDateTime]
    FROM [rotary_rotarian]
    where [createdDateTime] > CAST(@createdDateTime AS DateTime)
      end
     END
```

so please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it:   With your current stored procedure, you have to pass a parameter.  Even if you pass a blank parameter or a NULL parameter, you still have to pass a parameter.  The only way to get the error you got is to call the procedure without passing a parameter at all.

If you want your stored procedure to work even if no parameter is passed, then you have to give the parameter a default value, like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectRotarian_AllByCreatedDatetime]
    @createdDateTime varchar(50) = ''
AS
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectRotarian_AllByCreatedDatetime]
    @createdDateTime varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
```

Allow your parameter to be nullable/optional like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectRotarian_AllByCreatedDatetime]
    @createdDateTime DateTime = NULL
AS
BEGIN
```

also note, you should be passing in a `datetime` as a `datetime`, not a `varchar`

then:

```
if (Coalesce(@createdDateTime,'') = '')
```

can become

```
if (@createdDatetime IS NULL)
```